# How to pick up `.vercel` environment variables when running Next locally

Tags: next.js, vercel

When using `vercel env pull` it places an env file in the `.vercel` folder. For example `vercel env pull --environment=production` will create `.vercel/env.production.local`.

I would like to run the next dev server or local production build so that it uses those env variables, but when running `next dev` or `next start` it seems to only pick up env files from the repository root.

How can I make those commands pick up the pulled files from the `.vercel` directory? Or where these env files not meant to be used like that?

Answer (score 1):

When using `vercel env pull` with the `--environment` flag, it creates an `.env.production.local` file in the `.vercel` folder like you said. But by default, Next.js doesn't *automatically* get environment variables from that folder. To make Next.js pick up environment variables from the `.vercel` folder, you need to configure it to do so:

- Create a next.config.js in the root of your Next.js project
- Install the dotenv package if you haven't done so already: `npm install dotenv --save-dev`.
- Inside next.config.js, you use the dotenv package to load environment variables from the desired location.

Use the following code in your next.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(process.cwd(),'.vercel/env.production.local') });
```

You can then add your configurations in `module.exports`.